# How can i do Stripe payment direct transfer to merchant account?

Tags: stripe-payments, payment, credit-card

How can i do adaptive payment with credit card in Stripe. Payment should directly transfer to merchant bank account.

Can anyone give solution for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all required document here.

https://cartalyst.com/manual/stripe/2.0

Comment: Thanks it's useful for my solution.

Answer (score 0):

Recipient service no longer available in stripe it's deprecated. it's replaced with [connect](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/migrating).